# How to setup heartbeat for Google Analytics 4 Gtag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Recently google analytics announced that it gonna end support for old google analytics and want webmasters to move to google analytics 4 (GA4)

So they provide basic google analytics code to track website visitors, but Average User Engagement is not even 1 Minute for my website because it is an online chat room, once the chat loads in iframe the events are not tracked by google analytics.

[image]

This is my old google analytics code with heart beat to send signal to google analytics that the user is still active on the site.

```
<script>(function(d,e,j,h,f,c,b){d.GoogleAnalyticsObject=f;d[f]=d[f]||function(){(d[f].q=d[f].q||[]).push(arguments)},d[f].l=1*new Date();c=e.createElement(j),b=e.getElementsByTagName(j)[0];c.async=1;c.src=h;b.parentNode.insertBefore(c,b)})(window,document,"script","https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");ga("create","UA-Google Analytics Code Goes Here-1","auto");ga("send","pageview");function ga_heartbeat(){console.log("Firing heartbeat");ga("send","event","heartbeat");setTimeout(ga_heartbeat,5*60*1000)}ga_heartbeat();</script>
```

But in new GA4 it is not possible, so i want to add heart beat for GA4 analytic code, if someone help me it might be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same with GA4:

```
<script>
(function ga4_heartbeat(){console.log("Firing heartbeat");gtag("event","heartbeat");setTimeout(ga4_heartbeat,5*60*1000)}());
</script>
```

given that you use the "Global Site tag (gtag.js)" code from *Admin ... Data Streams ... Tagging Instructions ...*

**Complete Example (replace G-XXX with your own Measurement ID):**

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXX');
  (function ga4_heartbeat(){console.log("Firing heartbeat");gtag("event","heartbeat");setTimeout(ga4_heartbeat,5*60*1000)}());
</script>
```